# Disable notifications for subsequent messages from same sender

Tags: sms, notifications

Is it possible to, either through the OS or third-party app, to disable subsequent text message notifications from the same sender? For example, Sender A sends four text messages in the span of 30 seconds. I would like to receive a single notification rather than four separate ones.

Answer (score -1):

Give Tasker (Found in the play store) a try! It's a great app for things like this.

Comment: Ah, I have Tasker, but didn't know it had this capability. I'll check it out. Thanks!

Comment: Maybe using the plugin called AutoNotification would be even better